# How to intercept error request and redirect to a custom page?

Tags: redirect, error-handling, liferay, liferay-6

Here is one of the use-case as to what I want to do:

1. A User clicks on a blog-link or directly pastes the blog-link in the URL
2. The blog portlet is on the private-page of a Community (Site).
3. Since the user is not a member of the Community (Site) he would be taken to the error page.
4. He is shown, either a 404 page or a No-access error page.
5. **My requirement starts:** Now instead of showing the above pages or a customized version of the above pages.
6. I want to Intercept the request for 404 or other such requests.
7. And redirect to a portal page (not a static error page) based on some parameters of the User and the initial request parameters.
8. In this case I would want the user to be redirect to any public page of the same Community (Site) and ask him to Join or request membership for that Community (Site).

So in short I would want a way to intercept the request which generates the error and then redirect to where ever I want.

Is this available in liferay? If not can I get some idea as to how can I achieve this?

**Environment:** Liferay 6.1 GA2

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: I have posted this on [liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/18595033) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way (and the way I have redirect 404 errors to a specific page in the community) is to override the 404.jsp with a Hook. Then add your custom logic to the overridden JSP.

I'm assuming something similar could be done for no-access.

Comment: Thank You! You are saying to directly modify the original 404 error page in `docroot/errors/404.jsp`?

Comment: I'm saying use a hook to override the 404.jsp, and add logic to it that does you're redirection (or whatever else you need to do). For example I have overridden it to automatically redirect to a custom error page for each community rather than a shared 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `JSP` page to manage 404 errors as described [here in that Liferay's forum post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11279934).

In that `JSP` you can put your custom logic based on whatever param (the user, the community, etc..) that you can access from inside the JSP using, for example, the `themeDisplay` object.

Comment: Thank You! So were do I put the `/errors/404-searchworkings.jsp` in `EXT` or a `plugin`? and what about the other errors? Can you give some more details in this regards?